# R match ignore case and special characters

Tags: r, regex, string, match

I have searched and found similar answers but not exactly what I need.

I want to identify matches in 2 strings, ignoring case and spaces and special characters.

```
list1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
list2 <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
list3 <- c('a-', 'B_', '- c')
```

All below should give the same output (1 2 3)

```
match(list1, list1)
match(list1, list2)
match(list1, list3)
```

I have tried `str_detect(list1, regex(list2, ignore_case = TRUE))` but that doesn't give the same type of output (and I don't know how to incorporate the special characters/spaces in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that @Allan Cameron posted a very similar solution right before me... going to leave this anyways because different enough.. ?!

```
list1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
list2 <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
list3 <- c('a-', 'B_', '- c')
```

regex to replace any symbol that is not an alphabetic character with an empty string:

```
f <- function(x) {
  return(tolower(gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", x)))
}

match(f(list1), f(list2))
match(f(list1), f(list3))
match(f(list2), f(list3))
```

Comment: Yes, sufficiently different I think. The version you chose would probably depend on the exact use case, though both do the same thing here.

Comment: In my case, my reprex wasn't perfect - in my real data, my strings have > 1 letter, so this solution works for me.

Comment: Glad I could help! Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

You can create a regex that pulls out only the letters in the middle of the strings using `gsub`, and then convert them to lowercase. You can then use standard `match` on the result. Best to put all this in its own function:

```r
list1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
list2 <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
list3 <- c('a-', 'B_', '- c')

match2 <- function(a, b)
{
  a <- tolower(gsub("(.*)([[:alpha:]]+)(.*)", "\\2", a))
  b <- tolower(gsub("(.*)([[:alpha:]]+)(.*)", "\\2", b))
  match(a, b)
}

match2(list1, list1)
#> [1] 1 2 3
match2(list1, list2)
#> [1] 1 2 3
match2(list1, list3)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an explanation of what the regex is doing for people who might not be able to decipher it